# Pointers of FILE?

Tags: c

Currently learning the C programming language, I'd like to get in practice some of my knowledge in pointers and file writing. I chose so to write a little software, however, it does not write into the file, there is the the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INIT_FAILED 0
#define INIT_SUCCESS 1

int init(char filename[], FILE* logFile);

int init(char filename[], FILE* logFile){

    FILE* fileToWrite = NULL;
    char dir[] = "logs\\";
    strcat(dir, filename);

    fileToWrite = fopen(dir, "w");

    if(fileToWrite!=NULL){

        \\ I think the error is on this line below, but I'm not able to determine why

        *logFile = *fileToWrite;
        return INIT_SUCCESS;

    } else{

        return INIT_FAILED;

    }   

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char filename[] = "log";
    FILE* logFile = malloc(sizeof(FILE));

    if(logFile == NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    if(init(filename, logFile)){
        fputc('A', logFile)
    }
}
```

I would obviously take with pleasure every suggestions to a better readability of my code.

Thank you.

Comment: You get a `FILE` pointer, you need to read the source file, and write into the destination file the data. For example you use `fread` and `fwrite` functions

Comment: You have `strcat(dir, filename);` but there is *no room at all* to concatenate onto `char dir[] = "logs\\";` I suggest, say,  `char dir[100] = "logs\\";`

Comment: `FILE* logFile = malloc(sizeof(FILE));` is only confusing the code. There is no need to allocate memory for a single pointer.

Comment: I presume you are trying to read a text/log file. See [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Also, make it a habit to close the file stream after usage with [`fclose()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose).

Comment: @Ruks Right now, I'm just trying to write into the text file. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you explain why the malloc confuses the code ? Don't I need to allocate some memory for the FILE ?

Comment: All you need is a pointer variable, not a pointer to memory elsewhere. You can define `FILE *logFile` and pass `&logFile` to an argument `FILE **logFile` and set it with `*logFile = fileToWrite`. Notice the difference in the `*`s and that you should pass the *address* of the file pointer.

Comment: @NuxDD that does not allocate memory for the file *content*. I posted an answer with a commented working version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some corrections to the code, shown by comments. It's not necessary to allocate memory for a single pointer. You already need a pointer to a pointer as the function argument, so it just complicates things. This passes the address of the file pointer to the function, so it can set the variable in `main`.

Note that your string would overflow, I added some spare length, although this quick fix could be improved, perhaps with `strncat`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INIT_FAILED 0
#define INIT_SUCCESS 1

int init(char filename[], FILE** logFile);

int init(char filename[], FILE** logFile){  // double star

    FILE* fileToWrite = NULL;
    char dir[100] = "log\\";                // enough length for strcat
    strcat(dir, filename);

    fileToWrite = fopen(dir, "w");
    if(fileToWrite!=NULL){
        *logFile = fileToWrite;             // remove *
        return INIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    return INIT_FAILED;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char filename[] = "log.txt";
    FILE* logFile;                          // remove memory allocation

    if(init(filename, &logFile)){           // pass address of the FILE* pointer
        fputc('A', logFile);                // ; was missing
        fclose(logFile);                    // tidy up
    }
}
```

Comment: It does work exactly as I wanted to, thank you for your precious help.

Comment: I am just thinking why to return int and get FILE ** if it is enough to return FILE *

Comment: @P__J__ agreed that would be better, but I tried not to go too far from the faults in the OP's code.

Comment: IMO we should show beginners the correct/better/more_logical way of programming

Comment: @P__J__ I am, right now, trying to understand the way you did it in your answer to my question don't worry. I just didn't know that `=`could be used in logic, that's why I wanted to return an int !

Comment: @P__J__ there is a difficulty though, if someone has prepared a simplified code to illustrate the difficulty, and then be told "you should not even do it that way" when the code is for illustration. This answer addreses the points in the question: how to use the pointer, and correcting another fault so that the code runs. If I instead `return` a pointer, that does not show how to pass a pointer that can be modified.

Comment: @ArdentCoder As a beginner, I'd like to say, even if the answer of WeatherVane is not what PJ called the correct way of programming, it learnt me to write the code that was in my head, while the answer of PJ shows me how I should think about programming. Both of them was very useful to me

Comment: @NuxDD Yes, I don't disagree with that. I have upvoted this answer as well :)

Comment: @WeatherVane Oops I forgot to upvote your comment lol, I really liked that point ;)

Answer (score 2):

IMO you overcomplicate simple things. You do not have to return status as the status is your `fopen` result.

```
FILE *init(const char filename[])
{
    /* ... */

    return fopen(dir, "w");
}
```

and then

```
    if((logFile = init(filename))){
        fputc('A', logFile)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks PJ for this useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE* fileToWrite = fopen("yourfilename.txt", "wr/wb/eb/a...");
    if (fileToWrite==NULL){
        perror(NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Always check if the file is open properly. And read a little for the use of binary files

Comment: Kindly correct the typo. Missing a closing brace in line 1